# Keyboard accessible dropdown menu - html/css only

Tags: html, css

i have a html/css dropdown menu that i'm trying to access via the keyboard but cant get it to display on :focus

Example http://jsfiddle.net/2by45fyx/

Here's my html.  Notice that i've added a tab index to the list item so it can receive focus `<li tabindex="0" >`

```
<div id="topnav">
<div class="page">
     <ul>
        <li tabindex="0" ><a href="/">Example 1</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="/">Example Page 1a</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Example Page 2a</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Example Page 3a</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
        <li tabindex="0" ><a href="/">Example 2</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="/">Example Page 1b</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Example Page 2b</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
    </ul>   
</div>
```

You can view the complete css in the example link http://jsfiddle.net/2by45fyx/

Basically, the `dropdown` is `hidden` by default:

```
#topnav .dropdown { visibility: hidden; }
```

I can show it ok when the mouse hovers:

```
#topnav li:hover .dropdown { visibility: visible; }
```

I have tried adding the following to display the dropdown when the parent list item receives focus and the dropdown does show but i can't tab to it.

```
#topnav li:active .dropdown, #topnav li:focus .dropdown { visibility: visible; }
```

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to tab through this dropdown with keyboard only?

Comment: Probably, but it's likely you'll need the interaction to work off the anchor tags and not the list-items.  Logically you can't really focus on a list item, only a interactive element like and anchor or input.

Comment: You code works fine on my machine. I click under your items then click tab and the first dropdown appears

Comment: Hi @Dumisani yes it works fine if you click - i need it to be fully accessible via the keyboard using tab... no clicking!

Comment: I guess I'll have to create an empty page and test it from there. I'll get back to you  just now

Comment: Just tested on a new html page. It still works. I'm using chrome. I only open the page and click tab. What browser are you using?

Comment: I have tried in various browsers: Chrome 44, Firefox 42 and IE10.  All of them tab through the top level options ok but not the dropdown.  So i can tab to "Example 1" but i can't then tab to it's child dropdown options "Example Page 1a", "Example Page 1b" and "Example Page 1c" - instead "Example 1" tabs to "Example 2" so the dropdown is missed out.

Comment: Now that makes more sense. I'll have a look at it

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using the `accesskey` attribute:

see here: https://jsfiddle.net/70w6hru9/
and use the shortcuts mentioned below according the browser you are using.

Every browser use its own shortcut

- IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera 15+: [ALT] + accesskey
- Opera prior version 15: [SHIFT] [ESC] + accesskey
- Firefox: [ALT] [SHIFT] + accesskey

So you need to mention this on your web site for your users!

Comment: Please don't do this. Accesskeys have accessibility issues

Comment: @Ryan I know this, that's why I have mentioned that is necessary to let the users know how the can access the element according to the browser they are using

Comment: Hi @Franco I have tried the access key method and all it does is focus the parent tag, I still can't tab to the focused tab child dropdown options so no futher forward

Comment: Did you try my fiddle? If You open to the fiddle you need first to click on the frame where the links are "this i the right bottom frame" because this has to be the active one, and then according to the browser you are using use the right key combination.